# Verify if chrome is running using C Program

Tags: c

I want to develop a function in C that do some treatement  but it depends of the status of chrome Process .So if chrome is running then , I should kill the process to make the program executes correctly

```
If(chrome is running )
system("taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F");
Operation 1
operation 2
..........
```

So how can i translate the line if(chrome is running ) in c
I use windows

Comment: Why do you want to use C rather than a batch file?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/914782/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Yes i want to use C , because I started developing my program and some of functions must verfiy the status of chrome process .

Comment: Which Platform? Windows, Linux, MacOS,...?

Comment: Sorry , but I prefer the use of defined Functions not Tasklist .

Comment: I mention that i use windows in the description

Comment: Why not use `tasklist` if you are already using `taskkil`?

Comment: 'verfiy the status of chrome process' - it's Chrome - just assume it's broken:(

Comment: Just issue the `taskkill` ... if Chrome's not running, it won't do anything.

Comment: If Chrome is running ***where***? Somewhere in the universe? Inside the same physical machine case? On the same Windows instance? As the same user? With the same user profile? What you're asking to do simply does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, how about this?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
chrome_is_running() {
  return FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", NULL) != NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (chrome_is_running())
    system("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, We can.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
chrome_is_running() {
  char buf[BUFSIZ];
  int r = system("tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe\" > .out");
  FILE *fp = fopen(".out", "r");
  int found = 0;
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
    if (strncasecmp(buf, "chrome.exe", 10) == 0) {
      found = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  unlink(".out");
  return found;
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (chrome_is_running())
    system("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry , Can you suggest method that use defined function In C

Comment: Sorry, this was joke.